# Fix an error enable-migration C# using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to `enable-migrations` in Visual Studio 2022, but I get an error:

> PM> add-migration InitialCreate
> Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> Your startup project 'Project' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

I really need help about it. Thanks so much

Comment: The error seems quite clear. You have both ef6 and ef core added to your project. The build tools you are running are for ef core.  But you haven't added the ef core design package installer for the automatic migration scripts.

Comment: Please share the contents of you csproj file

Answer (score 1):

The following commands worked for me.

```
1. EntityFrameworkCore\Enable-Migrations
2. EntityFrameworkCore\add-migration
3. EntityFrameworkCore\update-database
```